# How to convert assembly to hex view

Tags: assembly, hex

I have this problem in assembly I need to do a reverse engineering and change the hex code but I don't know how to do this...

I have assembly code and I need to convert it to hex.

Example:

```
mov eax,3990Dh
```

I don't understand how to convert it to hex...

I need to do a reverse engineering and I don't know how to change the code to do what

I need to change from

```
.text:004016DE                 mov     eax, [esp+20h+var_4]
```

to this

```
.text:004016DE                 mov     eax, 3990Dh
```

Comment: @Jester `mov eax, [esp+20 h+var_4]` doesn't always mean `mov eax, 3990Dh`. I think some kinds of debugger is more useful than assembler in this case.

Comment: @MikeCAT Of course it doesn't mean that. The point is to change the machine code bytes so it does. And for that you use an assembler to get the bytes for `mov eax, 3990Dh`.